# Dyanmic width increase of user menu using CSS

Tags: css

I would like to know how would I dynamically increase the width of the user menu(which is an image), which could take any length of the menu item name. I am using below code.
The menu items in the user menu are shown on a image. Below is the code. Please let me know where should I make the changes. I am trying to use but I am failing to add menu items with large names(they overflow from the menu bar).

```
 user-menu ul li ul {
background: url("naviagtion-dropdwnbackgrd.png") no-repeat scroll left -30px transparent;
border: 0 none;
clear: left;
float: left;
left: -105px;
list-style-image: none;
padding: 15px 11px 0 0;
position: absolute;
top: 17px;
width: 145px;
z-index: 8; }
```

Comment: Will `white-space: nowrap;` help?

Comment: Removing the set width would probably help too! Also, floating **and** absolute positioning?

Comment: I have added white-space: nowrap; no luck and removed the set width, float and position but the menu is not widening dynamically. Do we have way to dynamically increase the width of this image??

Comment: Any ideas I am stucked up